# Which theorem tells about smallest field containing two given fields?

Tags: field-theory, splitting-field

Suppose $\mathbb{F} _{p^n}$ and $\mathbb{F} _{p^m}$ are two finite fields where p is a prime number and n,m$\in \mathbb{N}$, what is the smallest field containing these fields ?

Comment: Look up compositum.

Answer (score 2):

$\Bbb F_{p^k}\subseteq\Bbb F_{p^h}$ if and only if $k\mid h$. Therefore you are looking for $\Bbb F_{p^{\operatorname{lcm}(n,m)}}$.

Comment: Where can I get a proof of this statement and also that explains about the subfields of a finite field ?

Comment: I guess your algebra textbook should have that proof. I don't know what you are referring to in the second question.